# Intercommmunication between crewed space missions in all planets of solar system

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, communication, planet

As we know Human Communication taking place between Man in space, Man on Moon, Man on Mars (Future exploration) with Human beings on Earth planet where we are living with the help of control stations controlled by space agencies from different countries.

Is this also very much possible as per the scenario/s given below with advancement in space science and technology?

Human beings in one planet communication with Human beings in other planet excluding planet earth.

Of course, the exploration of crewed missions takes place taking into account whether life exists on other planets than planet earth, mars (possibility).

Just an assumption, that if life exists on other planets Or even if Life do not exists on other planets,what can be done in case a Human being on Mars planet would like to communicate with Human being on say Jupiter planet?

Examples :

Mars - Jupiter

Mars - Uranus

Mars - Saturn

Mars - Venus

Mars - Pluto

Mars - Mercury

Mars - Neptune

---

Jupiter - Mars

Jupiter - Uranus

Jupiter - Venus

Jupiter - Mercury

Jupiter - Pluto

Jupiter - Neptune

Jupiter - Saturn

and all other permutations & combinations of one planet communication with other seven planets excluding earth.

So no direct communication between two planets but only possible with planet earth as interpreter or translator?

Example:

Mars & Jupiter would like to communicate with each other.

Mars - Hello - Earth

Earth - Hello - Jupiter

Jupiter - Hi - Earth

Earth - Hi - Mars

So no direct communication possible of Hello, Hi between Mars & Jupiter planets possible?

To simplify my question, in case Humans land on both planets Mars & Jupiter via earth planet, can they directly communicate with each other without taking assistance of Humans on planet Earth?.

Assumptions or even could taken as a fiction movie for life existing on both planets mars & jupiter as well as in all other planets of solar system for the above scenarios with permutations & combinations.

Interplanetary telecommunications setup in solar system.

If the astronauts visit the planets Jupiter, Venus, Saturn, Mercury, Neptune, Uranus, Pluto, will they be able to survive for specific time period in terms of days, weeks, months,years theoretically according to space & astronomy study?

Comment: Why would communication between two planets ever need to incorporate earth? What would make earth any special here?

Comment: I would assume, someone trying to land on Jupiter would have other problems than communication ;-)

Comment: @CallMeTom it certainly is *one* of the problems to be solved. But I'd agree, why someone being able to colonize Jupiter would have a problem with selecting to either hop through another planet's comm systems or do it directly, based on which is advantageous for the current situatio, is beyond me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a practical matter, Earth is likely to remain the central communication hub for the solar system for quite some time, even when missions on different planets would want to communicate with each other.

Interplanetary radio communication relies on:

1. Large transmitter power output
2. Large receiving antennas

Ideally you want both, but as spacecraft are bottlenecked by mass, they usually have neither. In the case of a craft on Mars communicating with the Earth, things still work out:

- When sending information to Earth, the craft has low transmission power, but we can compensate that by using large receiving antennas on Earth
- When receiving information form Earth, the craft has a small antenna, but we can compensate that by transmitting at large power from Earth.

But in your hypothetical scenario of a craft at Mars communicating with a craft on Jupiter, **both** sides have small antennas and low transmission power, and will thus not be able to communicate.

Building large communication infrastructure on Earth is much cheaper than in space, and is likely to remain so until we can figure out to reduce the cost of launch by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Disagree because "interplanetary radio communication" will go away and be replaced by optical in the not-so-distant future because a 20 kW transmitter or [liquid helium-cooled front-end receiver](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21269) at the end of 34 meter dish on Earth [can be replaced by a few watt laser diode and an avalanche photodiode or one of those superconducting thingies](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35709) at the end of a 20 or 50 cm diameter telescope. ([see also](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24441))

Comment: See also [Quantitatively, why will optical communication be better than X-band for deep-space communications?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35698) and [How is long-distance optical communications coming along in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15540) and [Are there plans or a program for an optical relay pathfinder for deep space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31923/12102) and [What optical design is used by the GEDI's receiving telescope and how is the secondary held in place?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32548) (optical com will look similar)

Comment: and [When will STP-3 launch with the new optical space coms test and why is it late?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46152) and [What GEO relay satellite will the ISS use for end-to-end optical communication with a ground station?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27685)

Comment: Also, Musk and Shotwell have talked about extending the Starlink network using longer-range laser comms and relay satellites to reach Mars and Starships in-transit. There's no reason to stop there or route all traffic through Earth.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I'm so intrigued that I've just asked ["...extending the Starlink network using longer-range laser comms and relay satellites to reach Mars and Starships in-transit" (Musk & Shotwell)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48551/12102) See also [Will future deep space optical communications “ground stations” actually be in space, or on the ground?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48550/12102)